# Gulp can't minify css, why?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I copy the root dir to output dir, then minify css files, found the css files can't minify.
If i delete the copy dependence and run, that success. Why?

```
gulp.task('minifyCss', ['copy'], function() {
    gulp.src('**/*.css')
        .pipe(minifyCss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dirOutput));
});

gulp.task('copy', function() {
    gulp.src(['**/*', '!**/*.sh', '!{build,build/**}', '!**/*.js'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dirOutput));
});

gulp.task('default', function() {
    del(dirOutput, function() {
        gulp.run('minifyCss');
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you really have a directory called `dirOutput`? That's what you're looking for in `minifyCss` task. In other places you are using dirOutput as a variable.

Comment: Yes,that take a error when i debug it, now i have modified and running,it only copy css files to dirOutput widthout minify. If i delete the copy dependence and run,it minify success.

Comment: resolved,it need return. Thank you very much!!